# How can I mount a directory from one Raspberry Pi to another

Tags: linux, mount, samba

I have the following problem:
I have 2 Raspberry Pi in my network and want to mount a directory from my Raspberry Pi 2, running Samba version 4.2.14-Debian to my new Raspberry Pi 4 running Samba version 4.9.5-Debian.

On my **Raspberry Pi 2** I defined in /etc/samba/smb.conf

```
[test]
  valid users = pi
  guest ok = yes
  path = /home/pi/test
  writeable = yes
```

Now I can mount this drive on my **Windows 10 PC**:

[image: Win10 PC]

Now I tried on my **Raspberry Pi 4** to mount this directory:

```
$ sudo mount.cifs //192.xxx.yyy.29/home/pi/test /home/pi/test -o user=pi,pass=xyz
```

but I get always the error message:

```
mount error(2): No such file or directory
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

I played around with the version option and tried all versions from 1.0 to 3.1.1 but no success :(

Comment: Since you have a Pi2 and Pi4 you will also want to look at any samba version differences. Beginning with samba 4.5, the `NTLMv1` auth was disabled. You will need to use `v2`. You can specify that in your `mount.cifs` command line as an option after `-o` with `sec=ntlmssp`. Win10 has also messed with the default auth over the last year. (I don't have details there -- but that should be part of your inquiry as well)

Comment: How can I move this question to  Raspberry pi StackExchange. Or do I need to create a new post there? Sorry, I am a newbie.

Comment: Flag your post and ask a moderator to move it.  But a very simple question:  does the **target** directory also exist?  Is there actually a `/home/pi/test` on the Pi4?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: I tried:
sudo mount.cifs //192.xxx.yyy.29/home/pi/test /home/pi/test -o vers=2.0,sec=ntlmssp,user=i,pass=xyz
but I get the same error

Comment: @tink: Yes, I have created a directory /home/pi/test on the Pi4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First **DO NOT** try to obscure Local IP addresses - they are private and inaccessible to anyone outside your network and just make your Question harder to read.

I have the following shares in my `/etc/samba/smb.conf` (I believe this may be standard to allow access to /home directories.)

```
[homes]
   comment = Home Directories
   browseable = yes
```

NOTE You mount a **share** not a directory. In your case this would be **test**

I can mount remote Pi with:-

```
sudo mount.cifs //MilliwaysPi4.local/pi /mnt/SDA2  -o user=pi
```

or

```
sudo mount.cifs //MilliwaysPi4.local/pi/bin  /mnt/SDA2  -o user=pi
```

NOTE Use a sensible mount point with root access, although you can in principle use any directory

NOTE # Testing the Share Access (on sharing server)
sudo smbclient -U ian //MilliwaysPi4/homes
sudo smbclient -U pi //MilliwaysPi4/pi

Then enter command at the smb: prompt

```
smb: \> ls
smb: \> quit
```

Comment: Thank you for your advise! I tried the smbclient command on my sharing Raspberry Pi and I get NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME. I assume there is something wrong with my Samba configuration. I will evaluate my smb.conf and see wehther I can find an error. I am just wondering why it works on my Windows PC?

Comment: Thank you Millyways! I finally made it using the mount.cifs command you proposed. There was a misconfiguration in my Raspberry Pi 4. I reinstalled it and then it worked. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @Detlev if this answer solved your problem then please mark it as accepted (the green tick).

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you may find the following script useful.

This uses `nfs` rather than `samba`, and requires `nfs` to be installed on the server `sudo apt install nfs-kernel-server` and `/etc/exports` to be configured. Mine contains the following to share homes:-

`/home/pi   *(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)`

This could easily be adapted to mount any directory

```
#!/bin/bash
# Mount Remote Pi HOME directory
# remotePi [REMOTENAME [USERNAME]]
# Defaults to MilliwaysPi4 pi
# 2018-12-16

R_MOUNT='/mnt/remotePi'

# Check/create Mount Point
if [ ! -e $R_MOUNT ]; then
    sudo mkdir $R_MOUNT
fi

if [ $# -eq 0 ] ; then
    REMOTENAME='MilliwaysPi4'
else
    REMOTENAME=$1
fi

if [  $# -eq 2 ] ; then
    USERNAME=$2
else
    USERNAME='pi'
fi

# echo "USER" $USERNAME
REMOTENAME+=".local"
# echo $REMOTENAME
REMOTEDIR=$REMOTENAME
REMOTEDIR+=':/home/'
REMOTEDIR+=$USERNAME
REMOTEDIR+='/'
# echo $REMOTEDIR

if [ ! -z "$(ls -A $R_MOUNT)" ]; then
    sudo umount /mnt/remotePi
fi

sudo mount $REMOTEDIR /mnt/remotePi/
```